# Is it a good practice to save images in the backend database in mysql/django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to create my personal web page. So in that I needed to put in the recommendations panel , which contains recommendations by ex employees/friends etc.

So I was planning to create a model in django with following attributes:-

1. author_name
2. author_designation
3. author_image
4. author_comments

I have following questions in my mind related to image part:-

1. Is it good practice to store images in the backend database?(database is for structured information from what i understand)
2. How to store images so that scaling the content and managing it becomes really easy?

Comment: Don't store images in databases, just store the path of image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.Not good, especially as it scales.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

When you think about what happens in the request/response cycle you'll know that your python scripts get interpreted by some modules. So if you're using apache for instance, mod_wsgi could be doing this work. 
Usually, you don't want your static files being served by this same process because that is not very efficient, static files being static. In a typical scenario, you'll want a very fast web server, say nginx serving your static content without "thinking". This delegation gives a very efficient and scalable design. As @Anentropic said, you could choose to host static media on a CDN.

Answer (score 2):

in short: no.

use Django's built in [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) and have your webserver serve the files from disk.

Alternatively you can use ImageField with a custom [storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/storage/) such as [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and put the files up on e.g. Amazon S3 and have them served from there (maybe adding something like CloudFront CDN in front)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to store the images in your server in some specific, general folder for this images. After that you store a string in your DB with the path to the image that you want to load. This will be a more efficient way to do this.